# Why does running Javascript in Python + Seleniuim get an undefined error?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to use Javascript to get a table body element on a page, if  I run it as soon as I can I get undefined, but if I wait a few seconds it works.

```
def get_row_list(browser):
    table_body = browser.execute_script("""
        var tbody = document.getElementsByClassName("sortable")[0].children[1]
        return tbody
    """)
    while table_body == None:
        browser.execute_script("""
            var tbody = document.getElementsByClassName("sortable")[0].children[1]
            return tbody
        """)
    return table_body.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
```

If I run this too early I get
`Message: TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined`

Comment: Your script is probably running before element you've looking for is rendered. Check GM start time options or otherwise delay execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this works while working with JS in Python, but this sure helps while executing JS only.

Try:

```
table_body = browser.execute_script("""
    document.onload = function() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("sortable")[0].children[1];
      return tbody;
    }
""")
```

This should wait till your DOM is loaded and then looks for the element required

Comment: If OP wants to use only `execute_script` this is the way to go... +1 yet best practice with selenium is to use wait methods...

Comment: will accept this it says i have to wait a minute, just what I wanted mate :)

Answer (score 1):

The element `sortable` is not rendered yet...

Ues [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to wait for the element to load:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "sortable"))
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I would like to use Javascript to find this element, as using your methods similar to yours originally left me with elements being missed sometimes

Comment: @MosheSlavin 's way is more preferable, if you want to do it like professionals.

Comment: if you want to use execute script then why use selenium, make extension or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

To get to why this is not working, the crucial component here is the error you recieve when it is too early.

Basically, the document has not loaded. This means that your DOM (Document Object Model) representation is not ready to be parsed yet.

Essentially what your code is going, is that the browser is executing the script before waiting for the document to be loaded. To get around this emit a signal when the DOM is ready.

Comment: I thought Javascript interacted directly with the DOM and would always be ready?

Comment: Nothing is ever always ready, the DOM is built by the browser. As a refresher, your DOM is created as your page is loaded, it can't be always ready because that would imply that the page was already present in memory.